# How to find list of cell data value at a specific cell positions?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, cell

I have this next code to select the cell position at a given condition. This is from a raster. As you'll see I'm using NumPy and Pandas for this:

```
f = np.column_stack(np.where(demData>0))
```

When I print f I get something like this:

```
print(f) 

[[  0  89]
 [  0  90]
 [  0  91]
 [  1  90]
 [  1  91]
 [  1  92]
 [  1  93]
 [  2  92]
 [  2  93]]
```

Now with this previous result, what I'd like to obtain is the data value at that cell position. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(demDataStage)
df.at[1,93]
```

And, the result:

```
618.965
```

I have in mind something like this next code but I only get a single value (the last one corresponding to the last cell in f) but not an array. The result B is a NumPy array but a single number is showing:

```
row = f[:,0]
col = f[:,1] 

for i in row:
    for c in col:
        B = df.at[i,c]
print(B)
720.123
```

As you can see it's not a list or array that returns the cell's data value from the raster at each row,col cell position. I have more that 200 columns and rows so it's easier with something similar to what I showed above but I haven't found the way yet. Any suggestion is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just use `demData[np.where(demData)] `?

Comment: Regarding your question, you are getting a scalar because by doing `B=df.at[i,c]` you erase the previous value. If you want a list, initialize `B=[]` as an empty list before enetering the FOR loop. Then add elements to the list in the loop using `B.append(df.at[i,c])`.

Comment: Thank you bousof, quite helpful! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get your list by appending to it:

```
B = []
for i in row:
    for c in col:
        B.append(df.at[i,c])
```

You can also convert your list to numpy array and call a single line for all this:

```
B = df.to_numpy()[demData>0]
```

Comment: Thank you! Appending the values to the list returned some zeros in between the values I'm looking for. More like `B = df.to_numpy()[demData>0]` gave me what I need :)